# In python 3.5.2, how to elegantly chain an unknown quantity of functions on an object than changes type?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

**Introduction**

I am not very certain the title is clear. I am not a native english speaker so if someones has a better summary for what this post is about, please edit !

**Environment**

- `python 3.5.2`
- `pyspark 2.3.0`

**The context**

I have a spark dataframe. This data, before being written to elastic search, gets transformed.

In my case, I have two transformations. They are `map` functions on the rdd of the dataframe.

However, instead of hard writing them, I want to make it so that I can give my function (that handles the data transformation) X functions that will be, one by one, applied to the dataframe (for the first function) and/or the result of the previous transformation function.

**Initial work**

This is the previous state, not desired, hard written:

```
df.rdd.map(transfo1) \
        .map(transfo2) \
        .saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile
```

**What I have so far**

```
def write_to_index(self, transformation_functions: list, dataframe):
    // stuff
    for transfo in transformation_functions:
        dataframe = dataframe.rdd.map(transfo)

        dataframe.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile
```

However, this has a problem: if the return of the first transformation is not a dataframe, it will fail on the second iteration of the loop because the resulting object does not have a rdd property.

**Working solution**

```
        object_to_process = dataframe.rdd
        for transfo in transformation_functions:
            object_to_process = object_to_process.map(transfo)

        object_to_process.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile
```

The solution above seems to work (does throw any error at least). But I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution or any built-in python solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one-liner:

```
from functools import reduce

def write_to_index(self, transformation_functions: list, dataframe):
    reduce(lambda x, y: x.map(y), transformation_functions, dataframe.rdd).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile
```

which, if written verbosely, should be identical to

```
dataframe.rdd.map(transformation_functions[0]) \
             .map(transformation_functions[1]) \
             .map(...) \
             .saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile
```